# ASCII to C64 Screen Codes In DASM Assembler

Tags: string, assembly, 6502, commodore

I'm learning assembly for the 6502 micro via a C64 emulator.  Currently trying to output strings to the screen.  Here is my code:

```
    processor 6502
    org $1000

    ldx #$00    ;using x register as column counter
print:
    lda message,x;load a with x bit from message
    sta $0400,x ;store this bit in row 0 col 0 address
    inx         ;x++
    cpx #$05    ;is x >= 5?
    bne print   ;if not x >= 5, loop again
    rts         ;return from program


message dc "HELLO"
hexmsg dc $08,$05,$0c,$0c,$0f
```

Because my editor (notepad++ on win 10) uses ascii-like char-codes, the `"HELLO"` in `message` is bits 48 45 4C 4C 4F.  This gives the following output in the top left corner of the screen:
[image]

This is correct I guess, by looking at the commodore screen codes table [here](http://sta.c64.org/cbm64scr.html).

If I change line 6 to `lda hexmsg,x` then I get exactly what I'm after, the word `HELLO`.

I'm not yet very familiar with DASM assembler and having trouble finding complete documentation of it (if it exists).  Most tutorials I've found just have you declare `message .byte "HELLO"` or something similar and it just works because the assembler they are using auto-converts the ascii-like text string to a commodore string automatically, but DASM doesn't seem to do that.

Does anyone know a way I can either get DASM to do this, or recommend another way to simply type strings into the assembler rather than manually typing my strings as a bunch of hex data?

Comment: BTW, this is the best documentation I can find for DASM: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/scholar/dasm.html.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the source of your problem is using capital letters in your source code.  Whether these are displayed as upper case or as graphics characters is determined by the current graphics mode of the C64.  Try using lower case and I expect you will see the upper case that you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is patched version of DASM aseembler.
http://iancoog.altervista.org/C/dasm2.20.07-iAN_Rev_N.rar

You can use `SCRU` and `SCRL` directives to convert ASCII->Screencode conversion.

```
label SCRU  "string"
label SCRL  "string"
```

`SCRU` is for making uppercase text even if entered lowercase. `SCRL` keeps casing.

Comment: I used DASM for years before finally jumping to KickAss three years back because it wasn't being actively maintained (or at least didn't look like it). Is this a fork, or a reinvigorated core release? It has a lot of features that I went to KickAss for, and I'm almost tempted to return to DASM if it's active again.

Comment: This a modified version. You can grab the original one from http://dasm-dillon.sourceforge.net/. It seems it was last updated on June 2015.

Answer (score 6):

Aha, ASCII encoding vs. Commodore screen codes. We've all been there. You have a few options:

1. Don't write directly to screen memory, but use the Kernal CHROUT routine instead (probably via the higher-level string-output routine). Then all you have to worry about is the differences between ASCII and PETSCII, but that's a story for another bed-time. Also, this is good for text but sucks for games as the Kernal is s-l-o-w compared to direct writes.
2. Write a little conversion routine that runs when your program starts, eats your string table, and spits out converted screen code equivalents. Fast and efficient, provided your strings are all together and you're not writing a ROM-based application (which would not be able to do an in-place conversion).
3. Write a DASM pre-processor which runs before DASM in your build script and basically does the same conversion as #2 above, but to the sourcecode before the assembler sees it. This can be a bit gnarly, and you have to be sure to back-up the original source before munging it.
4. Get the DASM sourcecode and patch it to invoke a user-exit for a new data-type (for screen codes) that does the same as #2 but on-the-fly during assembly. Very gnarly.
5. Use lower-case letters in your strings, which will translate to upper-case screen code equivalents during assembly. You may have overlooked the fact that what you're seeing is the **shifted** representation of the characters in the string, which in the default display mode is graphics symbols.

Speaking from experience of all 5 options, I've settled on #2.

Also: switch to [KickAssembler](http://www.theweb.dk/KickAssembler/Main.html#frontpage), which

- is newer, and actively maintained
- offers more powerful features
- integrates very well with VICE for debugging

Comment: Haha, I like the sound of gnarly and very gnarly.  I'll try #2 for now though, sounds like a good exercise.  Can you elaborate on 'provided your strings are all together'?  I assume you mean literally they should be all consecutive in memory.  AFAIK, putting all the `label dc <string>` lines together in one place in the asm source should accomplish this, and I simply access them with the labels, correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely - you can refer to each string by individual labels when writing them to the screen, but by keeping them together as a contiguous sequence in memory you can also treat them as a single 'n-byte' block when converting them at startup. This means you can do the conversion on all the strings in one fast loop.

Comment: I can write a routine that does `lda message,x`,`sbc $40`,`sta message,x` and loop for $05 times, but is this OK?  I don't know how to find what exact memory address my data block lives in.  I know the program starts at 4096d, but ...maybe I'm overthinking it?

Comment: Using the label as the address reference means you don't have to care about the actual address that the assembler has placed your string at. And if you had another string right after it, of (say) length 10, and of course with a different label, your loop would be unchanged except to increase the count from 5 to 15.

Answer (score 5):

Been a while since I programmed 6510.  (If you are not pressed for conserving every single byte of C64 memory..)  Also consider zero terminating your string(s) with say a 0 byte rather than terminating on length reached in the X register.  Makes it a little more convenient rather than working out string lengths :D

```
processor 6502
org $1000

printstring:
    ldx #$00
printstrlp:
    lda message,x
    cmp #0
    beq quitstr
    cmp #32         ;' ' character
    beq noconv
    cmp #33         ;! character
    beq noconv
    cmp #42         ;* character
    beq noconv
    cmp #48         ;numbers 0-9
    bcs numconv
conv:
    sec
    sbc #$40
noconv: 
    sta $0400,x
    inx         
    bne printstrlp
quitstr:
    rts
numconv:
    cmp #58
    bcc noconv
    jmp conv

message dc "** HELLO C64 WORLD! **",0
```

Answer (score 0):

if it can help, here is a little python script to do it.
Just call it with `python3 str_conv.py code.asm message`

```py
import argparse
import os

mapping = [
 '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '~', ']', '|', '\\', ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', 
 '\'', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
 ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?'
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert ASCII to C64 screen codes')
    parser.add_argument('file', help='assembly source code')
    parser.add_argument('label', help='label used in DASM')
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), args.file)
    backup = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), args.file) + ".bck"
    os.rename(filepath, backup)

    label = args.label
    new_code = []    
    found = False
    
    for line_nb, line in enumerate(open(backup)): 
        if line.find("\\b{}\\b".format(label)) and '"' in line:
            text = line[line.find('"')+1:line.rfind('"')]
            
            new_line = "{}:\t.byte ".format(label)
            for i, char in enumerate(text):
                new_line += "{}{}".format(mapping.index(char), ", " if i != len(text)-1 else "\n")
            
            print(line_nb, new_line)
            new_code.append("; {}".format(line))
            new_code.append(new_line)
            found = True
        else:
            new_code.append(line)
            
    if not found:
        print("Label {} not found!".format(label))
    else:
        with open(filepath, "w") as new_file:
            for line in new_code:
                new_file.write(line)
        
        print("Done!")
```