# 6510/6502 C64 Keyboard input print to screen & store in memory issue

Tags: assembly, 6502, c64, 6510

getting somewhere with this but by looking at the Screen Display section of my c64 Reference book, the characters I am typing in below are printing to screen correctly, but when recalled to be printed later again from memory they are not. :(

Basically, if type in an "A" I get the black spade symbol, "S" comes back as a heart symbol and "X" comes back as a club. I must state this doen't happen as I type in as the user, and see my text printed to screen - that works great. It only goes wrong when I hit RETURN as the user and the characters that I think are stored at $1000,x (with inx happening after ever key press) displaying as symbols further down in the allocated area, followed by @ symbols to make up the rest of what I can see is empty spaces in the rest of the byte.

Excuse the messy/over-newb-engineered code, I have been learning Assembly for just under a week or so - with only BASIC as a sorta foundation.

I ran the debugger and when entering "ASX" into the program, the memory location via the debugger looked like this...

**41 53 58 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ♠♥♣@@@@@@@@@@@@@**

```
;USER INPUTS NAME OF CORPORATION

getnamea
        ldx #00
        ldy #00
        jmp getnameb

getnameb
       ; ldx $0900   ; transfer the x value here to a safe address

        jsr $FF9F   ;SCNKEY, place ASCII character into keyboard queue
        jsr $FFE4   ;GETIN, this places the ASCII value into the Accumulator 

        BEQ getnameb ;loop until keys are pressed. Branch if zero
        
        JSR $FFD2    ;CHROUT, print it to the screen as it is being typed in.
        CMP #13      ; CMP looks for the carrige return
        BEQ Name2    ; if we find it we branch using BEQ to name2 for msg2 
        ldx $0900
        STA $1000,x  ; also store what is being typed in consecutively? 
        INX
        INY
        stx $0900
        JMP getnameb ; if we don't we loop!        
                    
                    ; * store exactly what has been typed by the user into a place 
                    ;   in memory and give it the varible name: corpname
                    ; * display some more program defined text that includes the 
                    ; users inputted string

msg1    text 'What is the name of your corporation?'
        byte 0

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;PRINT MSG 2

Name2   LDX #00       ; load into the x registry zero


cycle2  LDA msg2,x    ; load into A the msg2, the x sequence.
        CMP #00       ; compare memory and accumulator to the value 0?    
        BEQ reveal   ; branch/jump if the result in A is 0
        STA 1704,x    ; where on the screen does msg2 start?
        INX           ; inc x to move the print along 1 space?
        
        JMP cycle2    ; jump back to the beginning of cycle and do it all again.

; WHAT DOES THIS DO WHEN WE JUST CALL THE ADDRESS $1000?

reveal  LDX #00
reveal1 
        LDA $1000,x
        STA 1784,x
        INX
        TXA
        CMP #16
        BEQ exit
        JMP reveal1
exit    jsr *



msg2    text `New astro mining corp registration...
        byte 0
```

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: These are VIC-II (`41 53 58 00 ♠♥♣@`) screen codes. It's the lowest layer (not ASCII). Those you normally use if you bypass the ASCII layer and talk directly with the VIC. For example, 01 = A, and 02 = B, etc. (by default).

Comment: CMB prg studio is the assembler.

Comment: So how would I make sure that the ASCII codes are being stored into the memory or being converted when they come back? Would I have to find a way to reduce the codes to the likes of 01 etc for each respective ASCII character? How do I only store to an ASCII layer, am I using the wrong part of memory?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498617/ascii-to-c64-screen-codes-in-dasm-assembler

Comment: Have you disabled the normal IRQ? If not, the you do not need to call SCNKEY.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, but I would love to know if there was a better way of doing this...

```
        CLC            ; clear the carry
        LDA $1000,x    ; load the character
        SBC #63        ; subtract 63 from it to get the right character in the first set
```

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the behavior you mentioned in the question, but ended up getting carried away and used it as an excuse to play around with macros and procedures. I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior (testing in VICE your code seemed to do the right thing for me), but it was fun to muck around. You can see what I ended up with [here](https://github.com/larsks/c64-asm-getname).

Comment: Since you are clearing the carry before subtraction, you are subtracting with 64. (the carry should be cleared for addition, but set for subtraction). You could probably do `and #$BF` to clear bit 6.